# About making a mobile version of a website

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, web

I want to make a mobile version of a website (you know, those with .m in the URL). How is this done, and what is different from a regular website? Can I still make my website in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, or do I also need some additional tools for mobile sites?

Final question - is there a difference viewing a mobile website on an Android phone versus an iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How is this done?**

In the same way as you do websites, is just HTML/CSS/JS and a bit more.

**What is different from a regular website?**

Basically but not only:

- The display size is the biggest (or in this case, the smaller) difference, you have to take care of small displays and viewports.
- The user will interact with the finger and not with the mouse, so the clickable area must be bigger.

**Can I still make my website in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, or do I also need some additional tools for mobile sites?**

Yes you can (and should) use just HTML/CSS/JS but check for the different video/audio tags already on webkit mobile.

**Is there a difference viewing a mobile website on an Android phone versus an iPhone?**

Both come from webkit but they have small differences (like the touch events) but for mostly websites the differences are minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your mobile version using HTML/CSS just like any other website. There are guidelines you can follow to help you with the process. [Search Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=guidelines%20for%20mobile%20website).
You can also look at platforms that help you put things together like [jqTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com)

Answer (score 0):

A website, even a *mobile one*, is still a website, which means you'll use the same stuff as for any other *normal* website : HTML, CSS, Javascript, images...

The main thing you'll generally have to think about are :

- Mobile devices often have small screens, and various resolutions,
- Mobile networks are not really fast, and sometimes have awful ping ; so, your pages must be lightweight, and not include too many external files/images.
- Touch-screens mean you'll have to put some spaces arround the things that must be clickable *(to prevent the user from clicking the wrong link because two are too close)*
- iPhones and recent Android devices have some quite advanced browsers ; there should not be that many differences between them *(you might find more differences between android 1.6 and 2.3 than between android 2.3 and iPhone ; and there are also many different browsers on android)* -- still, don't forget testing on as many devices as possible